# How to run two versions of Backbone.js app for different user groups?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a small Backbone application that is currently running on a page within a Drupal site. Currently the Backbone application is served on a page with no authentication - any user can see it.

I would like to use *almost* the same Backbone application on another page that the user only sees if they are authenticated. However I would like to add some advanced features for these authenticated users.

The difficulty is that I'd like to use the same Backbone code for the two types of users, rather than having two separate Backbone apps. How would you recommend I do this?

I'm naively thinking of this sort of thing:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
   render: function() { 
      if (isAdvanced) { 
        //render advanced search options in template
      }

   },
   runSearch: function() { 
      if (isAdvanced) {
       // handle advanced options for client-side search
   }
});
```

The problem is that the JavaScript code will obviously be visible to non-authenticated users, and I'm guessing that they can set `isAdvanced` in their console, and unlock the advanced features that way?

(The authentication process itself is handled by Drupal. If the user is not authenticated to see page B, they are automatically forwarded to a login page. That isn't the problem - how to organise the JavaScript code is the problem.)

Do I need to maintain two separate versions of my Backbone app? Or is there a way I can share code between the two?

For context, this isn't a super-secure application, but the advanced features are paid, so I'd prefer it wasn't *trivially* hackable.

Comment: Just to clarify - there are no extra Ajax requests once the app is loaded, so no need to handle extra authentication once it's loaded, just what's sent back to the client when the page is first rendered.

Comment: To block that kind of hacking just disable that feature for non-advanced users. if user set isAdvanced he will get error from server.

Comment: But how do I disable the feature? (The search is all client-side.)

Comment: So you can't block user from doing that (why search is all client-side?). even by spliting views in 2 different file, user can change that by one of those browser extensions (if he can get file). I recommend using different files. not all users have time to get another js file (from another pro user) and inejct in your page (client-side) just for a feature (but every user can easily edit isAdvanced). Everything in client is in hands of user and he can do everything with that.

Comment: Thanks! The search is client-side because it's only searching a very small number of items - it's an entirely client-side application.

Comment: So you're suggesting I should have two files - e.g. simple.js and advanced.js - and basically just maintain two different versions of the Backbone app?

Comment: You're welcome dude. Yes, but just move those parts of code to advanced/simple that are advanced/simple not all of them. Do the same for templates (I don't know how you are handling templates with drupal but it's not impossible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in this case to minimize developments is just to uglify/minimize your app javascript that'd be the cheapest solution, only a very motivated person would spend time to go through obfuscated code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, have common features defined in a Backbone app, and for advanced features extend common app and add more features on top of it. while rendering depending on authentication level render either common/advanced app. With this whatever you add to common app would be available for both users, and whatever added to advanced app will be available only for advanced users.